# Calling a function more than once

Tags: c, pic

So I'm programming a PIC using a CCS compliler. I'm using timer interrupt and this interrupt calls a function, called chronometer, that I wrote twice. This is how it goes

```
void timer2_isr()
{
   j++;
   l++;
   z++;
   if (j==1)
   {
      timero=1;
      btndly=1;
      j=0;
   }
   user1= chronometer(x, l);
   user2= chronometer(pad.deger, z);
}
```

This function returns a struct and takes 2 integers as an argument. It works fine, when I just call the function once. However when, as in this case, I call the function twice, user2 is just equal to whatever user1 is and the code is not even working correctly. Any idea why?

```
chrono chronometer(int enable, int milicounter)
{
   chrono time;
   if(enable==1 && milicounter>=25)       // Eğer kronometre aktif haldeyse
      {
         milicounter=0;
         time.sec++;
         if(time.sec==60)
         {
            time.sec=0;
            time.min++;
         }
         if(time.min==60)
         {
            time.min=0;
            time.hour++;
         }
         if(time.hour==24)
            time.hour=0;
      }
   return time;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the chronometer code?

Comment: I added the function.

Comment: is it possible you pass the same parameters?

Comment: @Alon 

Didn't understand what you mean, the arguments are different from each other and I'm printing the results to a 2*16 LCD via different variables.

Comment: @user2202966 see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are starting to use the time struct without resetting it's members, resulting in unexpected results..
And even if it is somehow initialized.. it does not refer to the input parameters, so obviously the result will be the same..

Comment: Yes I do use time struct without resetting its members actually I thought I wouldn't have to clear the value from time. The functions are getting called every 40 milliseconds so kind of simultaneously , but how can I separate the first and the second return values?

Comment: What do you mean? why should they be different if there is no reference to the input variables?

Comment: I'm a little rusty in C. I thought every time a function got called, it used different addresses even thought they have the same variable names. So what I want to do is basically to separate the return variables each time the function got called.

Comment: it does, what parameters do you expect time to have when you ++ it?

Comment: No what I mean is for example when user2.sec is 17 and increases every second at the same time, user1.sec could have any value and should increase every second. These variables should be independent from each other.

Comment: They are indeed independent.. after returning from the function.. but they will return the same since they are not affected from the input parameters..

Comment: How can I prevent them from returning the same value. I'm clueless about the affection of input parameters.

Comment: I am no longer sure what your question is, or what you want to acheive

Comment: I think we agree on the problem here. The return values coming from two function calls are the same or appear to be the same even though they are independent. 
Basically I want to solve this problem.